# How to convert gifs to video while keeping framerate

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, gif, framerate

### edit: Looks like converting the gifs may not really be changing the frame rate, guess the question is moot.

I have a lot of gifs nested in multiple subdirectories and they have different frame rates between them. Right now I'm using this block:

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.gif) DO ffmpeg -y -stream_loop 0 -i "%~f" -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "fps=10,scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" "%~pf/%~nf.mp4"
```

As you can see all the mp4 files will come out with a fixed 10 fps regardless of the input gif's original framerate

If there's a better way to do it in bash or powershell then I'd happily use that too

Comment: I'm not quite following - if you'd like to keep framerate, why do you include `fps=10` in the command?

Comment: It's just a stop gap, most gifs have a low framerate so 10fps kind of matches most of them (It seemed to me that the conversion process messes with original gif's framerate)

Comment: looking at it closely it looks like I was wrong, the framerate in the video file's details differs from video to video so I suppose whatever is causing the apparent difference in framerate is something else entirely.

Comment: ffmpeg has an in-built conversion algorithm. Not quite sure how it exactly works but I'd recommend changing the question to what you'd expect from the outcome of that rather than `fps=10` which is ofc not what you need at all.